# Align two divs inside a div left and right

Tags: html, css

I have a div in the following format

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="row1">
      <div id="label1"></div>
      <div id="value1"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="row2">
     <div id="labe2"></div>
     <div id="value2"></div>
   </div>
  <div id="row3">
    <div id="label3"></div>
    <div id="value3"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve a layout, where all the values are aligned on top of each other to the right and labels to the left within each row.

I have tried using float:left and float:right like

css

```
#row1{
  display: inline
}
#value1{
  float:right
}
#row2{
  display: inline
}
#value2{
  float:right
}
#row3{
  display: inline
}
#value3{
  float:right
}
```

But, this css i tried is missing the layout and row items are colliding into each other. Can someone help what could be the issue?

Comment: Not sure if i understand u right.. here is [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LRjOXb), take a look on that..

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to display tabular data, why not use a `<table>` instead

Comment: If any of the posted answers solved your question, please accept it, if not, let us know that we can do to find you one that does

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with how a HTML table works, then you can use [`display:table-*`](http://colintoh.com/blog/display-table-anti-hero) properties. Btw, use class instead of id. Use id specifically for things such as DOM manipulation or forms. Do not use id for styling unless you have no other choice.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>inline</title>
  <style>
    #main {
      border: 5px dotted grey;
      display: table;
      width: 300px;
    }
    .row {
      display: table-row;
    }
    .value {
      border: 1px solid red;
      display: table-cell;
      width: 50%;
    }
    label {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      display: table-cell;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="main">
    <div class='row' id="row1">
      <label for='value1'>V1</label>
      <div id="value1" class='value'>44</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' id="row2">
      <label for='value2'>V2</label>
      <div id="value2" class='value'>ALPHA</div>
    </div>
    <div class='row' id="row3">
      <label for='value3'>V3</label>
      <div id="value3" class='value'></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your question right you want to have labels on the left and values on the right just in front of their labels.
Here is example for you http://codepen.io/g1un/pen/PGKEwB 
Add to your rows class `row` and to labels class `label` and apply the next css to it:

```
.row::after {
  clear: both;
  display: table;
  content: '';
}

.label {
  float: left;
}
```

And don't apply to your rows `display: inline;` - it just does harm to your code.

Comment: I think you worded that labels/values on /left/right wrong, you basically said the opposite of what you have in the pen

Comment: @Huangism you are absolutely right. Thanks! Have corrected this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution - rather simple, replaced your whole CSS (i.e. no other CSS):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}    
div {
  border: 1px dotted #fa5;
}
#main > div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49.8%;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GjvykB

Change the width value to any desired setting < 50%

P.S.: border isn't necessary, used only to visualize the elements, th very last padding also isn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to support older IE browsers, go with `flexbox`

*Side note: Don't use `id` like that, use `class`*

```css
.main > div {
  display: flex;
}
.main > div > div {
  margin: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
   <div class="row1">
      <div class="label1">1</div>
      <div class="value1">One</div>
   </div>
   <div class="row2">
     <div class="label2">2</div>
     <div class="value2">Two</div>
   </div>
  <div class="row3">
    <div class="label3">3</div>
    <div class="value3">Three</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

on my opinion - try display: inline-block; I will hope it help you.

Answer (score -1):

Looking through some [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp), it looks like you an try using position for left and right alignment. I would suggest trying out something like in the documentation:

```
.right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 300px;
}
```